# Asp.net mvc run on part of website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a current website running with asp.net 3.5. I have been using the asp.net ajaxtoolkit with update panels for a while and I'm starting to get tired of it. So I have been starting to look at asp.net MVC and jQuery instead. It looks great!

My website is quite large and it will take a loong time to rebuild it all in MVC. Therefore my question is if I can start now using MVC when adding new pages to my website and then start changing the content of the whole website step by step? Or does MVC require the whole website to run MVC at the same time?

Answer (score 3):

It can be done, check out the post here [mixing webforms and mvc](http://www.packtpub.com/article/mixing-asp.net-webforms-and-asp.net-mvc)

Scott Hanselman or Scott Guthrie also have blog posts detailing how to do this.

edit: here is an article by Hanselman explainging how t moix both as well as Dynamic Data
[Plug In Hybrids ASPNET WebForms And ASP MVC And ASP NET Dynamic Data Side By Side](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PlugInHybridsASPNETWebFormsAndASPMVCAndASPNETDynamicDataSideBySide.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can create an application folder on the webserver and call it something like "new", Then install the mvc project into the "new" directory. This should work fine. Your new pages go to the "new" directory and the old pages stay in the other directories. Only the pages under the "new" directory will be under MVC control. Your old pages can then have links to the new pages until everything is new.

Answer (score 0):

The post by scott & scott is a good read.  Besides I have written an explicit article on this.  Not sure whether you may find this ueful.

[ASP.NET Webforms and MVC in Harmony](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/webformmvcharmony.aspx)